# Solspace Calendar and SEO Lite

Tags: solspace, calendar, seo

I'm using both Solspace Calendar and SEO Lite. Was wondering how to get the {event_title} from Calendar to display in the browser title when the event detail page is viewed.

Any recommendations? Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is to just pass in either the `entry_id` or the `url_title` for this calendar entry, either of which should be easy enough to do on a detail page.

To know which would be best in your case I'd need to see key parts of your template(s), but here are a couple examples.

**Option 1:** Use the `entry_id` for your event from the URL:

```
{exp:seo_lite entry_id="{segment_n}"}
```

**Option 2:** Use the `url_title` for your event that is in the URL:

```
{exp:seo_lite url_title="{segment_n}"}
```

*Where `n` is the number of the segment that contains the entry id or url title.*

---

**OR Option 3:** If you're Seo Lite tag is already *within* your `calendar:events` tag, just pass the `entry_id` variable right in:

```
{exp:seo_lite entry_id="{entry_id}"}
```

If you need more help, just update your question to include the relevant template code.

Comment: Thanks, Alex! I was able to pass the url_title, and that worked.